# How to do a 301 redirect for an index.php?dynamic=url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 1 old index.php?etc_etc URL I would like to forward to a specific URL, but the 301 redirect is not working.

My rewrite conditions are:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have been using this format to rewrite URLs.

```
redirect 301 /index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=948&category_id=114&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=69 /739619-5004s-garrett-gtp38r-ball-bearing-turbo-kit-99-5-03-7-3l-power-stroke
```

This does not work. I imagine because Magento utilizes the index.php for the home page.

How would I permanently redirect that URL to a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` directive. You need to use mod_rewrite and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a condition. So right below `RewriteEngine On`, add:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=948&category_id=114&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=69
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /739619-5004s-garrett-gtp38r-ball-bearing-turbo-kit-99-5-03-7-3l-power-stroke? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You have a typo where it says "^age", should be "page". Yet, now that gets a redirect loop error.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @TravisHarshaw Fixed the typo, also I forgot a `?` at the end of the rule's target. That prevents the query string from getting appended to the end.